# vue.js и laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, blade

Такой вопрос, как использовать директивы blade
     @lang()
в шаблоне vue

Comment: https://medium.com/@serhii.matrunchyk/using-laravel-localization-with-javascript-and-vuejs-23064d0c210e

Answer (score 1):

Для этого нужно, чтоб этот шаблон был включен в глобальный шаблон blade, т.е. был обработан.
Но это шаблон vue, поэтому нужно передавать переводы другим способом. К примеру, загружать аяксом или передавать параметром компонента.